# Appium fails to identify native app popup in iOS

Tags: python, appium, robotframework, appium-ios

While doing test automation for iOS real devices, appium fails to identify the popups that appear after clicking elements that require inputs from a picker-list, for example those with `XCUIElementTypePickerWheel`. While `driver.switch_to.alert` seems to handle alerts with "yes and no" options, appium fails to even identify those popups that may require input from an element like that of XCUIElementTypePickerWheel. To solve this, one has to do a touch action on the screen. Later all the required `driver.page_source` is visible in the log. Example code with python:

```
TouchAction(driver).tap(None, 100, 467, 1).perform()
time.sleep(1)
e = driver.find_elements_by_ios_predicate('wdType == "XCUIElementTypePickerWheel"')
e[0].set_value('My Vehicle')
```

If you have an easier option to handle this in appium, welcome your suggestions.